# FTP.retrbinary fails

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a complete Python novice, so I apologize if the solution to my problem seems obvious. I'm having difficulty with some relatively simple code that I've written.  I've scanned several related questions that have already been posted, but I don't see where my code differs in any meaningful way from the solutions suggested.

I'm trying to write a program that will:

1. Establish a ftp connection to a remote server.
2. Change the working directory on the ftp server.
3. Retrieve a list of files in the working directory from the ftp server.
4. Find a file ending with a specific suffix from the retrieved list of files.
5. Retrieve the found file to a temporary directory (created by tempfile.mkdtemp()) on the user's local file system.

Steps 1 through 4 are working as expected.  Sadly, the last step is falling into my except clause.

Can anyone make a suggestion regarding what might be wrong with the following line of code?

```
ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + file, open(opsys.path.join(localTempDir, fileName)).write)
```

Your suggestions are greatly appreciated.  Thanks, in advance.

Comment: How is it failing? Is it giving a traceback? Is it hitting your own error handler? Is it just silently falling through? _Always_ include traceback if there is any, it helps us help you immensely.

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems:

```
- type(file) = incorrect value
- opsys.path.join(localTempDir, fileName) = incorrect value #nonexistent file
```

Thats all what comes to mind looking on presented line of code =)